# Get click, touch + hold + move event from inside an iframe containing VR (360 degree) link of different domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality

I have a VR (360 degree) link of one of my clients which is hosted on different domain. I am embedding that on my page inside an iframe.
Now I want to detect if and where the user visiting my page is clicking. The same function for touch + hold + move (for mobile phone and touchscreens).
I will write down the main objective so as to clear the requirement. The aim is to open the page containing the iframe in 2 different places (different users) and keep them synchronized. If one user clicks or uses touchscreen device to go through the virtual (360) link the same should reflect on the other side connected user (with the same coordinates so as to what or where the first user going through in the iframe link).
Would really appreciate the help. Please provide example if possible.
I am using PHP and JS (+JQuery) for website development and thinking about using FCM for synchronization. Kindly provide ammendments or suggestions in tech part as well.

Comment: Do you control the source code of the page that you are loading into the iframe?

Comment: Nope... It's a 360 degree video link generated through some software which creates links hosted on software provider's domain.